# Warning logging when run java to connect with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

I've added this in my code for connecting and take data from mongodb

```
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

But, a warning appears when i run my code

```
Apr 16, 2018 7:48:50 AM 
 com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
```

Does anyone have solution?

Comment: What does the logger have to do with connecting to mongo? And where do you see a warning?

Comment: Logger appears more than what i explained above when i have no written above code (logger code). I see on output when i run the project.